# Set Date Range in gapi class for analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on a function that gets data from the Google Analytics API. For parsing and reading this data, I am using the GAPI class from here. [GAPI from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)

How can I set a timerange there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate the $start_date and $end_date fields

See here:  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/wiki/GAPIDocumentation