# How to set dates in GAPI Google Analytics class?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the [GAPI](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) class ([gapi.class.php](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/blob/master/gapi.class.php)) for Google Analytics API.

This is the code:

```
<?php
  require 'gapi.class.php';
  define('ga_profile_id', 'your profile id');
  $ga = new gapi("XXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "key.p12");
  $filter = 'country == United States && browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome';
  $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, array('browser', 'browserVersion'), array('pageviews', 'visits'), '-visits', $filter);
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Browser &amp; Browser Version</th>
    <th>Pageviews</th>
    <th>Visits</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->getVisits() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    endforeach
  ?>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Total Results</th>
    <td><?php echo $ga->getTotalResults() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Total Pageviews</th>
    <td><?php echo $ga->getPageviews() ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Total Visits</th>
    <td><?php echo $ga->getVisits() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Result Date Range</th>
    <td><?php echo $ga->getStartDate() ?> to <?php echo $ga->getEndDate() ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I can't find how to change the date ranges.

By default, it's showing the status from 2014 to today — I think it's the life of the analytics account.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344527/set-date-range-in-gapi-class-for-analytics) but it's for an older version, which is not working now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this worked

```
 $start_date = ("2017-11-01");
 $end_date = ("today");

  $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, array('browser', 'browserVersion'), array('pageviews', 'visits'), '-visits', $filter,$start_date,$end_date);
```